# Access global variable from Robot Framework listener 3

Tags: robotframework

Not able to access global variable from Robot Framework listener 3.

I tried to access global variable with the help of BuiltIn() as below. But this is not working.
Please share if you have any ideas to do this.

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

def end_test(test, result):
    print("BROWSER = '%s'" % BuiltIn().get_variables()['${BROWSER}'])
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked on my machine. How do you run robot tests?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work like this:

```
BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${BROWSER}")
```